# AngularJs execution context (scope)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I got a valid code full of callback functions, **Callback hell**.

Here it is :

```
app.directive('destinationDirective', function () {
    function destinationController($http, $rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.getWeather = function (destination) {
            var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + destination.city
                + '&appid=' + $scope.apiKey
                + '&units=metric';
            $http.get(url).then(function success(response) {
                console.log('success', response);
                if (response.data.weather) {
                    destination.weather = {};
                    destination.weather.main = response.data.weather[0].main;
                    destination.weather.temp = response.data.main.temp;
                } else {
                    $scope.message = 'City not found';
                }
            }, function error(error) {
                $scope.message = 'Server error'
            });
        };
    }

    return {
        scope: {
            destination: '=',
            apiKey: '=',
            onRemove: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: './destinationDirective.html',
        controller: destinationController
    };
});
```

So I try to make it flatter with functions definitions like below, but it's seems the execution context can not resolve my `destination` variable. I try to bind the execution context and it's still can't resolve. Did AngularJS kind of "tweak" the execution context of the function?

```
app.directive('destinationDirective', function () {
    function destinationController($http, $rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.getWeather = function (destination) {
            var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + destination.city
                + '&appid=' + $scope.apiKey
                + '&units=metric';
            $http.get(url).then(success.bind(destination), error);
        };
    }

    function success(response) {
        console.log('success', response);
        if (response.data.weather) {
            destination.weather = {};
            destination.weather.main = response.data.weather[0].main;
            destination.weather.temp = response.data.main.temp;
        } else {
            $scope.message = 'City not found';
        }
    }

    function error(error) {
        $scope.message = 'Server error'
    }

    return {
        scope: {
            destination: '=',
            apiKey: '=',
            onRemove: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: './destinationDirective.html',
        controller: destinationController
    };
});
```

I also tried:

```
$http.get(url).then(angular.bind(this, success, destination), error);
```

and:

```
$http.get(url).then(success.bind(this, destination), error);
```

But now I got the content of the `destination` and lose the `response` of the API

EDIT ABOUT SUPPOSED DUPLICATION: My problem is unique because the subject is about angular context when defined multiples functions on a controller, I find a solution and I will post it right now.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to define a "private member attribute" for the "class" `destinationController` like below. The functions look back on the previous execution context and find the desired attribute. Not an evidence before I asked the question from my classic OOP background (Java, C# and PHP) when I had to reformat some callbacks hell like it was originally.

```
app.directive('destinationDirective', function () {
    function destinationController($http, $rootScope, $scope) {
        var _destination;

        $scope.getWeather = function (destination) {
            _destination = destination;
            var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + destination.city
                + '&appid=' + $scope.apiKey
                + '&units=metric';
            $http.get(url).then(success, error);
        };

        function success(response) {
            if (response.data.weather) {
                _destination.weather = {};
                _destination.weather.main = response.data.weather[0].main;
                _destination.weather.temp = response.data.main.temp;
            } else {
                $rootScope.message = 'City not found';
            }
        }

        function error(error) {
            $rootScope.message = 'Server error'
        }
    }

    return {
        scope: {
            destination: '=',
            apiKey: '=',
            onRemove: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: './destinationDirective.html',
        controller: destinationController
    };
});
```